# How do a do an XML Dump on this php file?

Tags: php, xml

Total newbie question, I know.

How do I do an XML dump to see the XML request that this php file is making?

I've been trying `var_dump()` and `print_r()` in various places and failing miserably.

I am getting an error when submitting this form. When asking the people that run this API, they said they need a XML dump of my request to track the problem down.

If there is more specific info needed, or if I need to include and of the `/includes/` files, please let me know. I'm new to XML and trying to learn.

When I put `var_dump($cdsHtml)`; after the line `echo($cdsHtml);`

I just get:

```
string(76) "
ID  Name
0 
"`
```

How can I see this in XML format?

```
<?php

require_once("../includes/classService2.php");

if (!isset($_POST['submit'])) {
?>

    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-    strict.dtd"> 
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>List Class Descriptions Demo</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../styles/site.css" />
        </head>

        <body>
            <form method="post" action="getClassDescriptions2.php">
                Source Name:
                <input type="text" size="25" name="sName"/><br/>
                Password:
                <input type="password" size="25" name="password"/><br/>
                SiteID:
                <input type="text" size="5" name="siteID" value="175259"/><br/>
                <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit"/>
            </form>

<?php
} else {

    $sourcename = $_POST["sName"];

    $password = $_POST["password"];
    $siteID = $_POST["siteID"];

    // initialize default credentials

    $creds = new SourceCredentials($sourcename, $password, array($siteID));

    $classService = new MBClassService();
    $classService->SetDefaultCredentials($creds);

    $result = $classService->GetClassDescriptions(array(), array(), array(), null, null, 10, 0);

    $cdsHtml = '<table><tr><td>ID</td><td>Name</td></tr>';
    $cds = toArray($result->GetClassDescriptionsResult->ClassDescriptions->ClassDescription);
    foreach ($cds as $cd) {
        $cdsHtml .= sprintf('<tr><td>%d</td><td>%s</td></tr>', $cd->ID, $cd->Name);
    }
    $cdsHtml .= '</table>';

    echo($cdsHtml); 
}

?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `var_dump($cdsHtml);` should do the trick. Throw in an `exit` after it to make sure you kill the rest of the execution while checking your output..

Comment: I edited my answer with the results of putting var_dump($cdsHtml); after the echo($cdsHtml);

Comment: There is no XML here anywhere, but if you want to see the content of `$cdsHtml`, right-click -> View Source in your browser or throw a `header('Content-Type: text/plain');` in the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mindbody API people gave me this info, and it worked:  Changing the line that reads `$classService = new MBClassService();` to `$classService = new MBClassService(true);` (note the true parameter being passed in) should force an echo of both the xml request you are sending and the response you are receiving. This parameter causes the SoapClient object used in our examples to invoke SoapClient's __getLastRequest() and __getLastResponse() calls.